# How to pass command key usage to QEMU Guest? (As in using Command-Q corresponds to the guest seeing Meta-Q, not quitting QEMU.)

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I'm trying to use a Linux VM on MacOS with QEMU but I'm having a problem: I need to change the config to set up hyprland all the way but hyprland looks for shortcuts involving the super (meta/command/windows) key but the host MacOS takes any command key shortcut I use, not passing it to the VM and causing unwanted host side effects as well.

How can I pass the command key to the VM without losing significant functionality of other keys?